# Is it possible to reduce a LQG into a PID?

Tags: matlab, control-theory, optimal-control, kalman-filter, reduction-of-order-ode

Assume that we have a LQG controller and our state space model is known. Now we are implementing an integral action into the LQG controller, so it would be a LQGI controller.

The LQGI controller are very similar to a PID controller, due to the proportional, integral and derivative actions. But the LQGI has one thing that the PID doesn't have - observer. In this case, the observer has a kalman filter.

So my question is:
Is it possible to "split" the LQGI controller, into several PID controllers, with an observer?

Let's say we are having a MDOF system for 3 hanging masses with dampers and springs. That would be 3 PID and 3 observers, if we convert the LQGI controller into PID's?

The reason why I'm asking this question is because I want to build a LQGI with only analog electrical components. Matrix algebra is not easy in analog electrica components, but creating a PID with analog electrical components is super easy!

Comment: No.

Unless you are willing to use many PID controllers connected by sum blocks. I don't know what is the least number of PIDs you'd need but it's no less than ⅓ of the order of the system.

But then any implementational advantage disappears.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know how create a LQG with analog electical components?

Comment: A time-invariant LQG controller is made up of integrators, sums, and multiplication by constants. It's straightforward to construct these elements using analog components.

Comment: Yes I know! Building a LQR is quite easy and very similar to PID. But how about an estimator?

Comment: An LTI observer is likewise made up of integrators, sums, and multiplication by constants.

Comment: What about the kalman filter then ?

Comment: The time-invariant Kalman filter is an observer, so, likewise. Constructing a time-varying system using analog components tends not be be very practical.

Comment: Ok! Thank you. I will constructing a observer at my PLC.